# TCPClient Buffer size exception

Tags: c#, buffer, tcpclient

I am using simple TCP client app to send request to server. 
This is client code that sends client message to server.
The server sends a response, but sometimes the response is an empty string.

I catched a breakpoint when it happened and saw that when i put mouse over `client.ReceiveBufferSize` it shows exception `ObjectDisposedException`.

Here is the code:

```
private string SendClientMsg(string textToSend, string handID)
{ 
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverIP, port);
    NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
    //---create a TCPClient object at the IP and port no.---
    byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);

    //---send the text---
    nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

    //---read back the text---
    byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
    int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
    string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead);
    client.Close();
    return response;
    }
 }
```

This method belongs to a class. 
Multiple threads are using this method to send requests to server. 
Could it be that one thread opens the connection and starts sending
but at the same time another thread closes the connection using `client.Close()`

I am not sure if all threads are sharing the same TcpClient object.
(Is it a singleton object so it is shared by all threads?). 
If so I would have to put lock to make sure multiple threads are not accessing this method at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time this method is called a new instance of `TcpClient` is created:

`TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverIP, port);`

Only the calling thread has access to this instance, so that is not the issue.

The problem is that you are assuming that you will receive the entire
response in a single read:

`int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);`

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This can be less than the number of bytes requested if that many bytes are not currently available, or zero (0) if the end of the stream has been reached.

It takes time for the server to respond and it takes time for the response
to be sent across the network. When you call `Read` the entire response 
may or may not be available yet, so you need to read in a loop until the
end of the stream is reached.

```
var responseBuffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
var bytesRead = 0;
int read;
do
{
   read = nwStream.Read(responseBuffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
} while (read > 0)
```

This is assuming the server closing the connection properly after handling the request.
If the connection remains open you will have to restort to a different method
to determine you have received the entire response to the request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Idea looks good but you have to declare int read before the loop. Is "read" variable just use to know when is the last message? Could you please provide the whole function instead of just few lines to get the whole picture, because i am not sure if i understood it?

Comment: `read` is not there to identify the last `message`. In fact, from the `TcpClient` point of view there are no messages, only a stream of bytes. When you call read, if bytes have arrived on the network interfaces, read > 0. The concept of a `message` exists only in the protocol you have defined on top of this. If your setup is such that you send a single request, the server sends the response and then closes the connection, all you have to do is read until `read` is 0, otherwise you will have to keep reading and extract the `messages` yourself.

Comment: To identify the end of a message you could either add some bytes that mark the end of a message or add a prefix that sets the length of a message.